# Why can't one be cured with Asheira wood?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, maseches-pesachim, martyr

The Gemara in Pesachim ([25a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=25&format=pdf)) says

> א"ר יעקב א"ר יוחנן בכל מתרפאין חוץ מעצי אשירה היכי דמי אי נימא דאיכא סכנה אפילו עצי אשירה נמי ואי דליכא סכנה אפילו כל איסורין שבתורה נמי לא לעולם דאיכא סכנה ואפי' הכי עצי אשירה לא  דתניא ר' אליעזר אומר אם נאמר בכל נפשך למה נאמר בכל מאודך ואם נאמר בכל מאודך למה נאמר בכל נפשך אלא לומר לך אם יש אדם שגופו חביב עליו מממונו לכך נאמר בכל נפשך ויש אדם שממונו חביב עליו מגופו לכך נאמר בכל מאודך ושפיכות דמים ע"ז הא דאמרן

The Gemara says that one is not allowed to cure oneself with Asheira wood, *even where there is sakana* (danger to life). It seems that it's not referring to using Asheira wood as an idol, but to using it as a medication.

Is Issur Hanaha (prohibition of benefit) of Avoda Zara a Yehareg Ve'Al Yaavor (commandment that one must give up his life rather than commit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Tosafos there (Pesachim 25a)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00880.html#HtmpReportNum0046_L2) which says that it's not referring to the **medical** aspects of the wood, buyt to its **supernatural** affects, which possibly brings one closer to idol worship.:

> **חוץ מעצי אשירה.** נראה לר''י דמיירי כגון שאין יכול להתרפא משאר עצים אלא בזה כגון על ידי שדים או שום דבר אחר משום דאתי למיטעי בתר ע''ז

Similarly in [Avoda Zara 27b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01326.html#HtmpReportNum0051_L2) Tosafos ד"ה  שאני מינות דמשכא says that it refers to some special aspects of specifically this piece of wood:

> בכל מתרפאין חוץ מעצי אשירה ואור''י דמיירי כגון שאומר לו שאותם מים או אותם עצים מועילין ולא אחרים כגון ע''י שד שמטעהו כי לפעמים יש כח ביד שדים להטעות כדי לטרדם

So - as you suspected - Issur Hanaha (prohibition of benefit) of Avoda Zara does not require Yehareg Ve'Al Yaavor (commandment that one must give up his life rather than commit). At least we cannot prove it from this Gemara.